# How to sort a permutation cycle in the mapping form?

Tags: mathematica, permutation-cycles, sorting

Consider a cycle $(6\;  1\;  4\; 3\; 5\; 2  )$ of a symmetric group $S_n$ of degree $n$. This implies $6$ maps to $1$, $1$ maps to $4$, $4$ maps to $3$, $3$ maps to $5$, $5$ maps to $2$ and $2$ maps to $6$. Therefore there is a $2 \times 6 $ associated matrix $$\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1\;2\;3\;4\;5\;6  \\ 4\;6\;5\;3\;2\;1
\end{array}
\right).$$    By using **Mathematica**, I want to write the same cycle in associated matrix form $$\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1\;2\;3\;4\;5\;6  \\ 4\;6\;5\;3\;2\;1
\end{array}
\right).$$
I have to do the same for each cycle $(a\;\;  b\;\;  c\;\; d\;\; e\;\; f  )$ of length $6$ in $S_6.$  
 Please suggest Mathematica commands or provide a Mathematica code.

Comment: I've added an revised answer in order to document our joint work. I've also generalized the result using a method implementation. We can calculate the desired permutations using arbitrary $n$ now.

Answer (score 2):

After a nice discussion with Rohit Kumar, which can be found in the chat linked in the comments, we came up with a solution which I have extended in order to generate all desired permutations in a loop.

We use [Permutations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permutations.html) to generate all permutations of the set $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ and use [ToCycles](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/ToCycles.html) in order to convert each permutation to cycle notation. If the length is equal to $n$, we have found a match Here is the code:

```
f[n_Integer]:= Module[{l={}},
    Do[
      If[Length[j]==n,AppendTo[l,{Range[n], i}]], {i, Permutations[Range[n]]}, {j,ToCycles[i]}];
{l}
]
```

**Edit:** You might need to use

> Needs["Combinatorica`"] // Quiet

at the very beginning.

**Example:** Let us use $n=4$ for an easier example. We simply call the above function: $f[4]$ which yields to

> {{{{1,2,3,4},{2,3,4,1}},{{1,2,3,4},{2,4,1,3}},{{1,2,3,4},{3,1,4,2}},{{1,2,3,4},{3,4,2,1}},{{1,2,3,4},{4,1,2,3}},{{1,2,3,4},{4,3,1,2}}}}

Converting each entry via [MatrixForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateAMatrix.html) to a visiualized matrix representation yields to:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2 &3 &4  \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2 &3 &4  \\
2 & 4 & 1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2 &3 &4  \\
3 & 1 & 4 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2 &3 &4  \\
3 & 4 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2 &3 &4  \\
4 & 1 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2 &3 &4  \\
4 & 3 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

With corresponding cyclic notations:

$$(2\ 3\ 4\ 1), \ (2\ 4\ 3\ 1), (3\ 4\ 2\ 1), (3\ 2\ 4\ 1), (4\ 3\ 2\ 1), (4\ 2\ 3\ 1)$$

Notice that there are exactly $(n-1)!$ solutions.

For $n=6$, $f[6]$ yields to the following (truncated) output:

> {{{{1,2,3,4,5,6},{2,3,4,5,6,1}},{{1,2,3,4,5,6},{2,3,4,6,1,5}},{{1,2,3,4,5,6},{2,3,5,1,6,4}},{{1,2,3,4,5,6},{2,3,5,6,4,1}},
> ⋯112⋯
> ,{{1,2,3,4,5,6},{6,5,2,1,4,3}},{{1,2,3,4,5,6},{6,5,2,3,1,4}},{{1,2,3,4,5,6},{6,5,4,1,3,2}},{{1,2,3,4,5,6},{6,5,4,2,1,3}}}}

Using [Length](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html) on $f[6]$ yields to $120=(n-1)!=(6-1)!=5!$.

Comment: Dear David, thanks for your help. I have some problem with this cycle  (6 1 4 3 5 2), following your given step I got a matrix whose entries (1 2 3 4 5 6) are just above the cycle (6 1 4 3 5 2), this simply implies that 5 maps to 5 (just look at the fifth entry of the first row and the fifth entry of cycle).  But in this cycle, 5 maps to 2. Therefore, there is an associated matrix corresponding to a cycle of length 6.

Comment: No, I generated the permutations,  **not** the **cycles**. Following your example: If you use my described method, then $(6 1 4 3 5 2)$ is not a cycle but a permutation. This simply means that at the first entry is a $6$, at the second there is a $1$ and so on, while in cycle notation this means that $6 \to 1 \to 4 \to 3$ and so on. Writing each permutation in the provided matrix form, then generates each possible permutation of length $6$. Let me provide an example in my answer.

Comment: Dear David, I have edited my question.

Comment: I see, so you are not interested in all permutations of the symmetric group, but just for all of length $6$ given cycle notation. Well it is easy to change the code to do what you want, since all desired results are in $l$ anyway.

Comment: Can you please help me how I can filter the results for length 6  cycles?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: There is an error "Do::iterb: Iterator {i,Derangements[6]} does not have appropriate bounds. >>" .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119505/discussion-between-david-scholz-and-rohit-kumar).